# Magento admin : Fatal error: Call to a member function toOptionArray() on a non-object

Tags: magento

I am getting error in admin panel after adding plugin.

Error :

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function toOptionArray() on a non-object in /var/lib/openshift/5374ca8999fc775bdc00009d/app-root/runtime/repo/php/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/System/Config/Form.php on line 463
```

**Here is the code :**

```
 public function toOptionArray() {
    return array(
         array('value'=>'0', 'label'=>'No Credit'),
        array('value'=>'1', 'label'=>'Credit Only Invited Customer'),
        array('value'=>'2', 'label'=>'Credit Only Customer who invite'),
        array('value'=>'3', 'label'=>'Credit Both Customer')
    );
```

**Form.php file :**

```
<?php
```

class Mage_Adminhtml_Block_System_Config_Form extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Form
{

```
const SCOPE_DEFAULT = 'default';
const SCOPE_WEBSITES = 'websites';
const SCOPE_STORES   = 'stores';

/**
 * Config data array
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $_configData;

/**
 * Adminhtml config data instance
 *
 * @var Mage_Adminhtml_Model_Config_Data
 */
protected $_configDataObject;

/**
 * Enter description here...
 *
 * @var Varien_Simplexml_Element
 */
protected $_configRoot;

/**
 * Enter description here...
 *
 * @var Mage_Adminhtml_Model_Config
 */
protected $_configFields;

/**
 * Enter description here...
 *
 * @var Mage_Adminhtml_Block_System_Config_Form_Fieldset
 */
protected $_defaultFieldsetRenderer;

/**
 * Enter description here...
 *
 * @var Mage_Adminhtml_Block_System_Config_Form_Field
 */
protected $_defaultFieldRenderer;

/**
 * Enter description here...
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $_fieldsets = array();

/**
 * Translated scope labels
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $_scopeLabels = array();

/**
 * Enter description here...
 *
 */
public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->_scopeLabels = array(
        self::SCOPE_DEFAULT  => Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('[GLOBAL]'),
        self::SCOPE_WEBSITES => Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('[WEBSITE]'),
        self::SCOPE_STORES   => Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('[STORE VIEW]'),
    );
}

/**
 * Enter description here...
 *
 * @return Mage_Adminhtml_Block_System_Config_Form
 */
protected function _initObjects()
{
    /** @var $_configDataObject Mage_Adminhtml_Model_Config_Data */
    $this->_configDataObject = Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/config_data');
    $this->_configRoot = $this->_configDataObject->getConfigRoot();
    $this->_configData = $this->_configDataObject->load();

    $this->_configFields = Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/config');

    $this->_defaultFieldsetRenderer = Mage::getBlockSingleton('adminhtml/system_config_form_fieldset');
    $this->_defaultFieldRenderer = Mage::getBlockSingleton('adminhtml/system_config_form_field');
    return $this;
}

/**
 * Enter description here...
 *
 * @return Mage_Adminhtml_Block_System_Config_Form
 */
public function initForm()
{
    $this->_initObjects();

    $form = new Varien_Data_Form();

    $sections = $this->_configFields->getSection(
        $this->getSectionCode(),
        $this->getWebsiteCode(),
        $this->getStoreCode()
    );
    if (empty($sections)) {
        $sections = array();
    }
    foreach ($sections as $section) {
        /* @var $section Varien_Simplexml_Element */
        if (!$this->_canShowField($section)) {
            continue;
        }
        foreach ($section->groups as $groups){
            $groups = (array)$groups;
            usort($groups, array($this, '_sortForm'));

            foreach ($groups as $group){
                /* @var $group Varien_Simplexml_Element */
                if (!$this->_canShowField($group)) {
                    continue;
                }
                $this->_initGroup($form, $group, $section);
            }
        }
    }

    $this->setForm($form);
    return $this;
}

/**
 * Init config group
 *
 * @param Varien_Data_Form $form
 * @param Varien_Simplexml_Element $group
 * @param Varien_Simplexml_Element $section
 * @param Varien_Data_Form_Element_Fieldset|null $parentElement
 */
protected function _initGroup($form, $group, $section, $parentElement = null)
{
    if ($group->frontend_model) {
        $fieldsetRenderer = Mage::getBlockSingleton((string)$group->frontend_model);
    } else {
        $fieldsetRenderer = $this->_defaultFieldsetRenderer;
    }

    $fieldsetRenderer->setForm($this)
        ->setConfigData($this->_configData);

    if ($this->_configFields->hasChildren($group, $this->getWebsiteCode(), $this->getStoreCode())) {
        $helperName = $this->_configFields->getAttributeModule($section, $group);
        $fieldsetConfig = array('legend' => Mage::helper($helperName)->__((string)$group->label));
        if (!empty($group->comment)) {
            $fieldsetConfig['comment'] = Mage::helper($helperName)->__((string)$group->comment);
        }
        if (!empty($group->expanded)) {
            $fieldsetConfig['expanded'] = (bool)$group->expanded;
        }

        $fieldset = new Varien_Data_Form_Element_Fieldset($fieldsetConfig);
        $fieldset->setId($section->getName() . '_' . $group->getName())
            ->setRenderer($fieldsetRenderer)
            ->setGroup($group);

        if ($parentElement) {
            $fieldset->setIsNested(true);
            $parentElement->addElement($fieldset);
        } else {
            $form->addElement($fieldset);
        }

        $this->_prepareFieldOriginalData($fieldset, $group);
        $this->_addElementTypes($fieldset);

        $this->_fieldsets[$group->getName()] = $fieldset;

        if ($group->clone_fields) {
            if ($group->clone_model) {
                $cloneModel = Mage::getModel((string)$group->clone_model);
            } else {
                Mage::throwException($this->__('Config form fieldset clone model required to be able to clone fields'));
            }
            foreach ($cloneModel->getPrefixes() as $prefix) {
                $this->initFields($fieldset, $group, $section, $prefix['field'], $prefix['label']);
            }
        } else {
            $this->initFields($fieldset, $group, $section);
        }
    }
}

/**
 * Return dependency block object
 *
 * @return Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Form_Element_Dependence
 */
protected function _getDependence()
{
    if (!$this->getChild('element_dependense')){
        $this->setChild('element_dependense',
            $this->getLayout()->createBlock('adminhtml/widget_form_element_dependence'));
    }
    return $this->getChild('element_dependense');
}

/**
 * Init fieldset fields
 *
 * @param Varien_Data_Form_Element_Fieldset $fieldset
 * @param Varien_Simplexml_Element $group
 * @param Varien_Simplexml_Element $section
 * @param string $fieldPrefix
 * @param string $labelPrefix
 * @return Mage_Adminhtml_Block_System_Config_Form
 */
public function initFields($fieldset, $group, $section, $fieldPrefix='', $labelPrefix='')
{
    if (!$this->_configDataObject) {
        $this->_initObjects();
    }

    // Extends for config data
    $configDataAdditionalGroups = array();

    foreach ($group->fields as $elements) {
        $elements = (array)$elements;
        // sort either by sort_order or by child node values bypassing the sort_order
        if ($group->sort_fields && $group->sort_fields->by) {
            $fieldset->setSortElementsByAttribute(
                (string)$group->sort_fields->by,
                $group->sort_fields->direction_desc ? SORT_DESC : SORT_ASC
            );
        } else {
            usort($elements, array($this, '_sortForm'));
        }

        foreach ($elements as $element) {
            if (!$this->_canShowField($element)) {
                continue;
            }

            if ((string)$element->getAttribute('type') == 'group') {
                $this->_initGroup($fieldset->getForm(), $element, $section, $fieldset);
                continue;
            }

            /**
             * Look for custom defined field path
             */
            $path = (string)$element->config_path;
            if (empty($path)) {
                $path = $section->getName() . '/' . $group->getName() . '/' . $fieldPrefix . $element->getName();
            } elseif (strrpos($path, '/') > 0) {
                // Extend config data with new section group
                $groupPath = substr($path, 0, strrpos($path, '/'));
                if (!isset($configDataAdditionalGroups[$groupPath])) {
                    $this->_configData = $this->_configDataObject->extendConfig(
                        $groupPath,
                        false,
                        $this->_configData
                    );
                    $configDataAdditionalGroups[$groupPath] = true;
                }
            }

            $data = $this->_configDataObject->getConfigDataValue($path, $inherit, $this->_configData);
            if ($element->frontend_model) {
                $fieldRenderer = Mage::getBlockSingleton((string)$element->frontend_model);
            } else {
                $fieldRenderer = $this->_defaultFieldRenderer;
            }

            $fieldRenderer->setForm($this);
            $fieldRenderer->setConfigData($this->_configData);

            $helperName = $this->_configFields->getAttributeModule($section, $group, $element);
            $fieldType  = (string)$element->frontend_type ? (string)$element->frontend_type : 'text';
            $name  = 'groups[' . $group->getName() . '][fields][' . $fieldPrefix.$element->getName() . '][value]';
            $label =  Mage::helper($helperName)->__($labelPrefix) . ' '
                . Mage::helper($helperName)->__((string)$element->label);
            $hint  = (string)$element->hint ? Mage::helper($helperName)->__((string)$element->hint) : '';

            if ($element->backend_model) {
                $model = Mage::getModel((string)$element->backend_model);
                if (!$model instanceof Mage_Core_Model_Config_Data) {
                    Mage::throwException('Invalid config field backend model: '.(string)$element->backend_model);
                }
                $model->setPath($path)
                    ->setValue($data)
                    ->setWebsite($this->getWebsiteCode())
                    ->setStore($this->getStoreCode())
                    ->afterLoad();
                $data = $model->getValue();
            }

            $comment = $this->_prepareFieldComment($element, $helperName, $data);
            $tooltip = $this->_prepareFieldTooltip($element, $helperName);
            $id = $section->getName() . '_' . $group->getName() . '_' . $fieldPrefix . $element->getName();

            if ($element->depends) {
                foreach ($element->depends->children() as $dependent) {
                    /* @var $dependent Mage_Core_Model_Config_Element */

                    if (isset($dependent->fieldset)) {
                        $dependentFieldGroupName = (string)$dependent->fieldset;
                        if (!isset($this->_fieldsets[$dependentFieldGroupName])) {
                            $dependentFieldGroupName = $group->getName();
                        }
                    } else {
                        $dependentFieldGroupName = $group->getName();
                    }

                    $dependentFieldNameValue = $dependent->getName();
                    $dependentFieldGroup = $dependentFieldGroupName == $group->getName()
                        ? $group
                        : $this->_fieldsets[$dependentFieldGroupName]->getGroup();

                    $dependentId = $section->getName()
                        . '_' . $dependentFieldGroupName
                        . '_' . $fieldPrefix
                        . $dependentFieldNameValue;
                    $shouldBeAddedDependence = true;
                    $dependentValue = (string)(isset($dependent->value) ? $dependent->value : $dependent);
                    if (isset($dependent['separator'])) {
                        $dependentValue = explode((string)$dependent['separator'], $dependentValue);
                    }
                    $dependentFieldName = $fieldPrefix . $dependent->getName();
                    $dependentField     = $dependentFieldGroup->fields->$dependentFieldName;
                    /*
                     * If dependent field can't be shown in current scope and real dependent config value
                     * is not equal to preferred one, then hide dependence fields by adding dependence
                     * based on not shown field (not rendered field)
                     */
                    if (!$this->_canShowField($dependentField)) {
                        $dependentFullPath = $section->getName()
                            . '/' . $dependentFieldGroupName
                            . '/' . $fieldPrefix
                            . $dependent->getName();
                        $dependentValueInStore = Mage::getStoreConfig($dependentFullPath, $this->getStoreCode());
                        if (is_array($dependentValue)) {
                            $shouldBeAddedDependence = !in_array($dependentValueInStore, $dependentValue);
                        } else {
                            $shouldBeAddedDependence = $dependentValue != $dependentValueInStore;
                        }
                    }
                    if ($shouldBeAddedDependence) {
                        $this->_getDependence()
                            ->addFieldMap($id, $id)
                            ->addFieldMap($dependentId, $dependentId)
                            ->addFieldDependence($id, $dependentId, $dependentValue);
                    }
                }
            }
            $sharedClass = '';
            if ($element->shared && $element->config_path) {
                $sharedClass = ' shared shared-' . str_replace('/', '-', $element->config_path);
            }

            $requiresClass = '';
            if ($element->requires) {
                $requiresClass = ' requires';
                foreach (explode(',', $element->requires) as $groupName) {
                    $requiresClass .= ' requires-' . $section->getName() . '_' . $groupName;
                }
            }

            $field = $fieldset->addField($id, $fieldType, array(
                'name'                  => $name,
                'label'                 => $label,
                'comment'               => $comment,
                'tooltip'               => $tooltip,
                'hint'                  => $hint,
                'value'                 => $data,
                'inherit'               => $inherit,
                'class'                 => $element->frontend_class . $sharedClass . $requiresClass,
                'field_config'          => $element,
                'scope'                 => $this->getScope(),
                'scope_id'              => $this->getScopeId(),
                'scope_label'           => $this->getScopeLabel($element),
                'can_use_default_value' => $this->canUseDefaultValue((int)$element->show_in_default),
                'can_use_website_value' => $this->canUseWebsiteValue((int)$element->show_in_website),
            ));
            $this->_prepareFieldOriginalData($field, $element);

            if (isset($element->validate)) {
                $field->addClass($element->validate);
            }

            if (isset($element->frontend_type)
                && 'multiselect' === (string)$element->frontend_type
                && isset($element->can_be_empty)
            ) {
                $field->setCanBeEmpty(true);
            }

            $field->setRenderer($fieldRenderer);

          if ($element->source_model) {
                // determine callback for the source model
                $factoryName = (string)$element->source_model;
                $method = false;
                if (preg_match('/^([^:]+?)::([^:]+?)$/', $factoryName, $matches)) {
                    array_shift($matches);
                    list($factoryName, $method) = array_values($matches);
                }

                $sourceModel = Mage::getSingleton($factoryName);
                if ($sourceModel instanceof Varien_Object) {
                    $sourceModel->setPath($path);
                }
                if ($method) {
                    if ($fieldType == 'multiselect') {
                        $optionArray = $sourceModel->$method();
                    } else {
                        $optionArray = array();
                        foreach ($sourceModel->$method() as $value => $label) {
                            $optionArray[] = array('label' => $label, 'value' => $value);
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    $optionArray = $sourceModel->toOptionArray($fieldType == 'multiselect');
                }

                $field->setValues($optionArray);
            }
        }
    }
    return $this;
}

/**
 * Return config root node for current scope
 *
 * @return Varien_Simplexml_Element
 */
public function getConfigRoot()
{
    if (empty($this->_configRoot)) {
        $this->_configRoot = Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/config_data')->getConfigRoot();
    }
    return $this->_configRoot;
}

/**
 * Set "original_data" array to the element, composed from nodes with scalar values
 *
 * @param Varien_Data_Form_Element_Abstract $field
 * @param Varien_Simplexml_Element $xmlElement
 */
protected function _prepareFieldOriginalData($field, $xmlElement)
{
    $originalData = array();
    foreach ($xmlElement as $key => $value) {
        if (!$value->hasChildren()) {
            $originalData[$key] = (string)$value;
        }
    }
    $field->setOriginalData($originalData);
}

/**
 * Support models "getCommentText" method for field note generation
 *
 * @param Mage_Core_Model_Config_Element $element
 * @param string $helper
 * @return string
 */
protected function _prepareFieldComment($element, $helper, $currentValue)
{
    $comment = '';
    if ($element->comment) {
        $commentInfo = $element->comment->asArray();
        if (is_array($commentInfo)) {
            if (isset($commentInfo['model'])) {
                $model = Mage::getModel($commentInfo['model']);
                if (method_exists($model, 'getCommentText')) {
                    $comment = $model->getCommentText($element, $currentValue);
                }
            }
        } else {
            $comment = Mage::helper($helper)->__($commentInfo);
        }
    }
    return $comment;
}

/**
 * Prepare additional comment for field like tooltip
 *
 * @param Mage_Core_Model_Config_Element $element
 * @param string $helper
 * @return string
 */
protected function _prepareFieldTooltip($element, $helper)
{
    if ($element->tooltip) {
        return Mage::helper($helper)->__((string)$element->tooltip);
    } elseif ($element->tooltip_block) {
        return $this->getLayout()->createBlock((string)$element->tooltip_block)->toHtml();
    }
    return '';
}

/**
 * Append dependence block at then end of form block
 *
 *
 */
protected function _afterToHtml($html)
{
    if ($this->_getDependence()) {
        $html .= $this->_getDependence()->toHtml();
    }
    $html = parent::_afterToHtml($html);
    return $html;
}

/**
 * Enter description here...
 *
 * @param Varien_Simplexml_Element $a
 * @param Varien_Simplexml_Element $b
 * @return boolean
 */
protected function _sortForm($a, $b)
{
    return (int)$a->sort_order < (int)$b->sort_order ? -1 : ((int)$a->sort_order > (int)$b->sort_order ? 1 : 0);

}

/**
 * Enter description here...
 *
 * @param Varien_Simplexml_Element $field
 * @return boolean
 */
public function canUseDefaultValue($field)
{
    if ($this->getScope() == self::SCOPE_STORES && $field) {
        return true;
    }
    if ($this->getScope() == self::SCOPE_WEBSITES && $field) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

/**
 * Enter description here...
 *
 * @param Varien_Simplexml_Element $field
 * @return boolean
 */
public function canUseWebsiteValue($field)
{
    if ($this->getScope() == self::SCOPE_STORES && $field) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

/**
 * Checking field visibility
 *
 * @param   Varien_Simplexml_Element $field
 * @return  bool
 */
protected function _canShowField($field)
{
    $ifModuleEnabled = trim((string)$field->if_module_enabled);
    if ($ifModuleEnabled && !Mage::helper('Core')->isModuleEnabled($ifModuleEnabled)) {
        return false;
    }

    switch ($this->getScope()) {
        case self::SCOPE_DEFAULT:
            return (int)$field->show_in_default;
            break;
        case self::SCOPE_WEBSITES:
            return (int)$field->show_in_website;
            break;
        case self::SCOPE_STORES:
            return (int)$field->show_in_store;
            break;
    }
    return true;
}

/**
 * Retrieve current scope
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getScope()
{
    $scope = $this->getData('scope');
    if (is_null($scope)) {
        if ($this->getStoreCode()) {
            $scope = self::SCOPE_STORES;
        } elseif ($this->getWebsiteCode()) {
            $scope = self::SCOPE_WEBSITES;
        } else {
            $scope = self::SCOPE_DEFAULT;
        }
        $this->setScope($scope);
    }

    return $scope;
}

/**
 * Retrieve label for scope
 *
 * @param Mage_Core_Model_Config_Element $element
 * @return string
 */
public function getScopeLabel($element)
{
    if ($element->show_in_store == 1) {
        return $this->_scopeLabels[self::SCOPE_STORES];
    } elseif ($element->show_in_website == 1) {
        return $this->_scopeLabels[self::SCOPE_WEBSITES];
    }
    return $this->_scopeLabels[self::SCOPE_DEFAULT];
}

/**
 * Get current scope code
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getScopeCode()
{
    $scopeCode = $this->getData('scope_code');
    if (is_null($scopeCode)) {
        if ($this->getStoreCode()) {
            $scopeCode = $this->getStoreCode();
        } elseif ($this->getWebsiteCode()) {
            $scopeCode = $this->getWebsiteCode();
        } else {
            $scopeCode = '';
        }
        $this->setScopeCode($scopeCode);
    }

    return $scopeCode;
}

/**
 * Get current scope code
 *
 * @return int|string
 */
public function getScopeId()
{
    $scopeId = $this->getData('scope_id');
    if (is_null($scopeId)) {
        if ($this->getStoreCode()) {
            $scopeId = Mage::app()->getStore($this->getStoreCode())->getId();
        } elseif ($this->getWebsiteCode()) {
            $scopeId = Mage::app()->getWebsite($this->getWebsiteCode())->getId();
        } else {
            $scopeId = '';
        }
        $this->setScopeId($scopeId);
    }
    return $scopeId;
}

/**
 * Enter description here...
 *
 * @return array
 */
protected function _getAdditionalElementTypes()
{
    return array(
        'export'        => Mage::getConfig()->getBlockClassName('adminhtml/system_config_form_field_export'),
        'import'        => Mage::getConfig()->getBlockClassName('adminhtml/system_config_form_field_import'),
        'allowspecific' => Mage::getConfig()
            ->getBlockClassName('adminhtml/system_config_form_field_select_allowspecific'),
        'image'         => Mage::getConfig()->getBlockClassName('adminhtml/system_config_form_field_image'),
        'file'          => Mage::getConfig()->getBlockClassName('adminhtml/system_config_form_field_file')
    );
}

/**
 * Temporary moved those $this->getRequest()->getParam('blabla') from the code accross this block
 * to getBlala() methods to be later set from controller with setters
 */
/**
 * Enter description here...
 *
 * @TODO delete this methods when {^see above^} is done
 * @return string
 */
public function getSectionCode()
{
    return $this->getRequest()->getParam('section', '');
}

/**
 * Enter description here...
 *
 * @TODO delete this methods when {^see above^} is done
 * @return string
 */
public function getWebsiteCode()
{
    return $this->getRequest()->getParam('website', '');
}

/**
 * Enter description here...
 *
 * @TODO delete this methods when {^see above^} is done
 * @return string
 */
public function getStoreCode()
{
    return $this->getRequest()->getParam('store', '');
}
```

}

Guide me how to resolve this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: show us relevant codes

Comment: i have added code kindly check

Answer (score 0):

Since you did not provide any code I can break down the basics.

That error means the object is empty.

If your code looked like this for example.

```
 $results->toOptionArray()
```

Then the error is telling you $results is not an instance of an object.